# text/event-stream render in grails from scratch(without plugin)

Tags: servlets, grails, controller, push

To use push method , we use the famous JS object EventSource :

This is the client part which is easy to develop it :

```
        var eventSource = new EventSource("controller/action");

        eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {

            document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = event.data;

        };
```

However , i get difficulty to configure push method in server part(Grails)  .

When , i peek in JEE app developped by Servlets , i can see that the server part is as following :

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //content type must be set to text/event-stream
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");  

        //encoding must be set to UTF-8
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

            writer.write("data: "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"\n\n");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

To convert this servlet to action controller :

```
def push(){

        render(contentType:'text/event-stream',characterEncoding:'UTF-8'){
              [dt:"data: "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"\n\n"]             
        }
}
```

and in client part :

```
 var eventSource = new EventSource(baseURL+"external/push");
 eventSource.onmessage=function(e){
     console.log(e.data.dt);
 }
```

Unfortunately, i don't get any result at console .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the render method will handle `'text/event-stream'` correctly, but you have direct access to the `response` object in the action:

```
def push() {
  //content type must be set to text/event-stream
  response.setContentType("text/event-stream");  

  //encoding must be set to UTF-8
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    response.outputStream.write("data: "+ System.currentTimeMillis() +"\n\n");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Comment: i knew this method and i have worked with it, However , i want to use the elegant syntax of render render(contentType:'text/event-stream'){}

Answer (score 2):

```
def push = {
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
    for(def i=0;i<10;i++) {
        render("data $i: ${System.currentTimeMillis()}\n");
        sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain your answer so the questioner understands what went wrong